# Help getting Arabic on Android

Tags: languages, localization

My Friend is going to sell his Nexus S because it does not natively support Arabic.
I have found several websites that claim to have a solution to this issue.
http://ardoid.com/ Seems to be the easiest solution to implement.

Has anyone tried this or any other solution?
Do the characters run together like how Arabic is written and not the single characters?
Will the menues change to Arabic?
Can he store contact names in Arabic?
What arabic does it use?
Will the push updates work?
Will the spell checker work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Persian and also have Nexus-S. You can upgrade your ROM to Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4).

This version of android has Arabic in it's localization and has all you want. If your provider support oem upgrade you can simply upgrade it by phone **OR** you can flash the latest Cyanogenmod ROM to your phone and have fun with your mobile.

You can always download latest Cyanogenmod Naghtly from [HERE](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=nightly&device=crespo)

Answer (score 1):

upgrading to ICS (android v4.0) will fix your problem, I would suggest that you wait for the Official ICS Rom (the official update published by Samsung) according to [engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2012/03/15/confirmed-ics-coming-to-the-nexus-s-in-the-next-few-weeks/)
it will be coming very soon.

However, if you do not want to wait and want to install a Custom Rom you can have a look at [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=883) they have several roms that you can install on your device.