# Gingerbread Claims Support for Arabic, but I Don't See the Language in Settings

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, languages, localization

Gingerbread claims to have support for Arabic, but I have 2.3.4 installed on my Google Nexus One, and Arabic is not an option when I go to my language settings.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html#locs

Anyone know how to enable the Arabic language or is Google not giving us the straight truth?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/install-additional-language-support-on-htc-desire-hd

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/help-getting-arabic-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live, what's your carrier, and how did you upgrade to 2.3.4?  Normally US firmware won't have Arabic, for example, since it would be wasting space on 99% of people's phones in the US.

That doesn't mean you can't add it.  I think [this page](http://ardoid.com/?p=27) provides a method for doing it, but I can't read Arabic :P

Answer (score 0):

Gingerbread DOES have support for Arabic. I've used it on my phone. However each supported language comes with files and such that need to be downloaded and installed. Each ROM is doing to be bundled with different language packs by default depending on where they expect the ROM to be used. If your ROM is from a country specific carrier, don't expect many languages!

The ROM I use comes in four flavors with about 25 languages each, and you download the version that has the languages you care to use. I use the one that has middle-east languages rather than the one that has eastern European ones for example.

Comment: Any ideas where might one find those file? I'm interested in Hebrew, but I assume it's the same situation

Comment: @Traveling: Usually this is something best done bundled in the ROM. What ROM do you have? (No I don't know how to do this independently of picking a ROM that's had it baked in.)

Comment: I have a Froyo 2.2 standard T-Mobile ROM. They're supposed to offer a Gingerbread update this month. But if it's region dependent, I may have to re-flash with Cyanogen or similar. I was really hoping there's just a language file out there I could just drag'n'drop into my phone... Oh well.