# Arabic support for my Android device

Tags: languages, localization

I've got a new phone (Samsung galaxy SII) with Android 4 on it.  I would like to be able to add Arabic support on it.  Is there a simple way to do so ?

I'm a newbie with Android related subjects, so I'm not able to handle complicated processes.

Comment: And by the way, ICS does support Arabic

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/help-getting-arabic-on-android

Answer (score 2):

ICS supports arabic, and you can add keyboard languages from the settings of the device

Answer (score 0):

If you have android 4, Arabic is already supported. You need only to get to setting then language system wide and change it to Arabic or any other language. Unfortunately you can't have the option of Arabic with arabic-western numerals 123. They only have the stupid option: Arabic with hindy numerals.

Answer (score 0):

Some of Samsung devices doesn't support Arabic even if it have ICS (Android 4), this usually happens if you ordered your device from outside (like from amazon), if you want to add Arabic, you'll have to flash a ROM that supports Arabic (like the official UAE ROM), if you bought the phone from an Arabic country, talk to the salesman.

For the keyboard just install any other keyboard from Google Play (e.g Go Keyboard, Swiftkey ...etc)