# Want to add Persian and Arabic on Samsung Galaxy Phone running Gingerbread OS

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-ace, languages, bluestacks

Peace be on you All...

Dear all...
I wan't to Add Persian and Arabic suppport on my Samsung Galaxy Ace having Gingerbread OS, All of my applications running in these languages show broken texts and fonts hence making it very difficult to read.

To get Persian I even added 'Iran' into my locale using 'morelocale 2' though the phone language got changed but the fonts were broken everywhere.

Tried using bluestacks on my PC, even bluestacks doesn't have support for both of these languages.

I've observed this issue on All of the Samsung Galaxy phones including Note and SIII.

In Sony and HTC phones this problem doesn't exist they've got great versatality in supporting diffrent languages.

Comment: See also: [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/16575), [Can I install additional language support (Russian) on HTC Desire HD without rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5303/16575), [Arabic support for my Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/16575)