# Arabic123 instea

Tags: languages, localization

I need to remove Hindy numbers off the Clock and date from the system of my nexus 7, when I have it in Arabic language.
I neeeeeeed numbers in this Format 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
Not in those middle eastern Format where
 Zero is a point and five is an o.
I know how to change Languages!!! My problem is with the format of the digits and numbers system wide.
So it is not a question that has been asked! Wake up guys.

Comment: Thank you to let us know! So do you have any question you want to have answered? Doing some guess-work: [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15361/16575), [Help getting Arabic on Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9757/16575), [Arabic support for my Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Just downloaded the Arabic language pack for [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) and [SwiftKey Tablet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.tablet.full#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIxMiwiY29tLnRvdWNodHlwZS5zd2lmdGtleS50YWJsZXQuZnVsbCJd).

The numbers on it are standard 123, with the option of Arabic numbers. It does offer prediction, though apparently the Arabic language is still in beta for prediction.

I love this keyboard. I've had it since the day I got into android. It updates often. I don't even have a Tablet, but I bought both just to give the developers more money. It's currently on sale for half off, as they just released flow (their version of Swype with multiple word support.)

Good Luck. Remember why we love Android. Everything is an app, and can be changed. (: